# The "Ten Commandments" enumeration compared to the Masoretic text

Tags: exodus, masoretic-text, ten-commandments

As noted in the popular modern Hebrew commentary on the Old Testament [*Da’at Miqra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da'at_Miqra), which quotes one of the leading modern scholars of Old Testament textual criticism, Rabbi Mordechai Breuer, there is a discrepancy between the orthography of the Ten Commandments in the Masoretic text and how they are counted in the Jewish tradition. According to the accepted Jewish enumeration, there is a missing ["parashah"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashah) break between the first and second commandments (Exodus 20:3-4), and an extra one in the middle of the tenth commandment (Exodus 20:14).

How is this discrepancy accounted for in the Jewish tradition (or any other tradition, for that matter)?

Comment: This is, actually, a very complex question and it would take a long answer to deal with satisfactorily. A good bit of the detail is laid out in the [Wikipedia "Ten Commandments" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Commandments#Traditions_for_numbering), though, and you should have a look at that in any case.

Comment: As currently phrased this question is off-topic and should be closed. The later traditions, whether Christian, Jewish or other are not a hermeneutical problem. The actual problem is how to explain the fact that there seem to be more commandments in the text than what we would expect from Exodus 34:28 and Deuteronomy 10:4.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim tweaked.

Comment: To be on-topic I think that you need to say that from a simple counting of the "thou shalt not"s and the "thou shalt" in the text, ignoring the parsha and verse breaks, it looks like there could be as many as 14 commandments in this list, but that Exodus 34:28 and Deuteronomy 10:4 both indicate that there are ten. So how do we explain that? Then you can say that reading by the parsha breaks leads to a count of ten commandments, but they are not the traditional ten commandments. So how do we explain that? This first question is on-topic, the second is less so.

Comment: I think your question is better suited for the [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange

Comment: The translation portion is on topic (albeit quite broad), but how various traditions account for it is best handled on sites for those respective traditions, such as [Judaism.SE] or [Christianity.SE]